# Web Scraping from an API Loop

Tags: python, api, web-scraping

I'm scraping from the World Bank for a paper and I'm trying to make a loop of the web scraping of different indicators but I can't seem to make it work until a certain part of the code. Hope someone can help please?

```
#Single Code for each indicator
indcator = 'SP.POP.TOTL?date=2000:2020'
url = "http://api.worldbank.org/v2/countries/all/indicators/%s&format=json&per_page=5000" % indicator
response = requests.get(url)
print(response)
result = response.content
result = json.loads(result)
pop_total_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(result[1])
```

This is the loop i'm trying to build but I got an error in the last part of below code:

```
#indicator list
indicator =  {'FP.CPI.TOTL.ZG?date=2000:2020','SP.POP.TOTL?date=2000:2020'}

#list of urls with the indicators
url_list = []
   for i in indicator:
   url = "http://api.worldbank.org/v2/countries/all/indicators/%s&format=json&per_page=5000" % i
   url_list.append(url)


result_list = []
for i in url_list:
   response = requests.get(i)
   print(response)
   result_list.append(response.content)

#Erroneous code
result_json = []
for i in range(3):
   result_json.append(json.loads(result_list[i])))
```

Comment: Could you please add what error you get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are making 2 requests (`FP.CPI.TOTL.ZG?date=2000:2020` and `SP.POP.TOTL?date=2000:2020`) your `result_list` length is 2, so its index are 0 and 1. Use `range(2)` or `range(len(result_list))` instead:

```py
import requests, json

#indicator list
indicator =  {'FP.CPI.TOTL.ZG?date=2000:2020','SP.POP.TOTL?date=2000:2020'}

#list of urls with the indicators
url_list = []
for i in indicator:
   url = "http://api.worldbank.org/v2/countries/all/indicators/%s&format=json&per_page=5000" % i
   url_list.append(url)


result_list = []
for i in url_list:
   response = requests.get(i)
   print(response)
   result_list.append(response.content)

#Erroneous code
result_json = []
for i in range(len(result_list)):
   result_json.append(json.loads(result_list[i]))
```

Comment: thank you! I thought that i can just put a range with maximum and it will just stop if there are no available item in the list :)